# Jenkins Maven Job Charset

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins, character-encoding, spring-test

I'm using Spring Test to test my Spring Application, which is basically a REST webservice that serves JSON and some other uploaded media.

The unit tests are working fine in all developer's machines, and some of them tests for strings returning inside the JSON responses, and a little subset of them tests special characters.

The application is completely configured to use UTF-8 with everything, however the JSON response is returning with the wrong charset, so the test fails.

I tried to configure on `/etc/default/jenkins` the following line:

`JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"`

But I still get the same result.

I also had the chance to see what `Charset.defaultCharset()` was, when running a particular test... And it appeared something like `US-ASCII`...

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How should i know without seeing your code nor you maven pom file?

Comment: Thanks, I went to get the code and found out what was wrong, lol. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong.

In my Spring Test configuration, I was reading a DML.sql file to create initial test data, and the line that initialized the database was like this:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/DML.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

That left my configuration dependent from the server charset, and in my case I had that weird "US-ASCII" set in my server.

I made it independent by setting the `encoding` attribute to `UTF-8`:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/DML.sql" encoding="UTF-8" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

So the values that came from the H2 database could be tested against values with special characters.